# Embed Google Autocomplete Places Detail on website

Tags: autocomplete, embed

I'm trying to embed place details on a website.  I can easily embed/display google streetview api using an iframe and src="http...",

but attempting to embed/display Autocomplete Places Detail using examples similar to "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/xml?input=Amoeba&types=establishment&location=37.76999,-122.44696&radius=500&key=YOUR_API_KEY"  from https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete  do not seem to work, is not showing anything in the iframe, and in Google Developer Console overview I'm seeing 'client errors (4xx)' which leads me to believe the key is okay but something else is wrong.

should this be working on a webpage simply using an iframe or am I missing something?

Comment: seems I need to add bootstrap library, but for some reason it is not accepting my API key.  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places

Comment: of course looking no where near as easy as I had hoped, apparently have to generate a bunch of php on page to get it to display --- if anyone knows any solutions on how to quickly add this to a webpage, most appreciated